# Print shopify product list in a page using api

Tags: ajax, api, shopify

GET /admin/products.json?collection_id=841564295

```
$.getJSON("/admin/products.json?collection_id=841564295", function(productData) {
console.log(productData);
});
```

using this code i'm getting all the products in a collection by collection id....
only if i'm logged in as admin..

if i'm not loggedin there is no response but "Status Code:303 See Other" error..

Comment: Where are you using that code? If you are using the Admin API you should use it from a server and never from the client.

If you need to get data on the client side, you should use the [StoreFront API](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/reference)

Comment: @ErnestoAndresGutierrez 
im using that code in js file..
hmm how can i user store front api in js to  list the products??
thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use the Admin API in a js file on the client side because that API is for consuming data from a server. You need a API key and secret, and you must keep the API secret safe.  Please read this to use the new StoreFront API: [Getting started](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/getting-started).  If you're modifying a theme you also can use Liquid, you can use the {Collection Object](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/collection). Could you give us more details about where are you using that and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I like to get the product list in the js .. and i couldn't find the code that we can use in the js...like admin api.

its like i need all the products from a list of collections and list all the products that have inventory > 0

Comment: is there any way to get products by collection using ajax api like this
jQuery.getJSON('/products/red-rain-coat.js', function(product) {
  alert('The title of this product is ' + product.title);
} );

Comment: are you modifying a theme? where do you want to get that information? is that a external website? a liquid page in the theme?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:
I am getting namespace of product using this api, you can get whatever you want in products.

```
var backvalues2=[]; 
var product_url='admin/products/2142613700675/metafields.json';   
  $.getJSON(product_url).then
   (function (data) {

      $(data.metafields).each(function (i, list) {

     backvalues2.push(list.namespace);
     });

   }).fail(function () {
      alert("Please Check Internet Connection")
     }).always(function () { });
    console.log(backvalues2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 303 is a redirect (to the login page).

Use the `/products` endpoint instead:

`$.getJSON("/products.json?collection_id=841564295", function(productData) {
  console.log(productData);
});`

Answer (score -2):

```
$.getJSON("/collections/#collection-handle/products.json", function(productList) {
console.log(productList);
});
```

Got all the products by collection....